TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support the context manager protocol
import os 
import json
import platform
import logging
import pymysql as pm
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import logging


class LogOutput:
    env=None
    config=None
    

    def __init__(self, env_filename):
        self.env=env_filename
        self.config=self.get_config()

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)
        
    def is_Windows():
        if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
            return True
        else:
            return False        

    def DB_connection(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        connection = None
        try:
            config=LogOutput.get_config(self)
            host=config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["host"]
            port=config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["port"]
            database=config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["db"]
            username=config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["username"]
            password=config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["password"]

            # Load the configuration from DB_conn_info_local.json
            config_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'DB_conn_info_local.json')
            with open(config_file_path) as config_file:
                config = json.load(config_file)

            connection = pm.connect(user=username,password=password,host=host,port=port,database=database)
    
            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection
    
    def logging_sp(self):
        logging_sp_query = """

        stored procedure query here 
     
        """
        with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                try:
                    cur.execute(logging_sp_query)

                except Exception as e:
                        logging.exception(e)

                else:
                    cnxn.commit()
   

def main():
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
        vfc=(cwd+"\\DB_conn_info_local"+".json")
    else:
        vfc=(cwd+"/DB_conn_info_local"+".json")
    ve=LogOutput(vfc)
    ve.logging_sp()
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I keep getting this error:
    with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support the context manager protocol

Is it because I am using "with"? Is there another way to execute it? It uses a json config file that it reads which contains the credentials. I didn't need to include that here. I saw other posts saying "with" return none so that's why it's executing basically nothing? I don't know how to re-write this because I am using with twice.

Check if self.DB_connection() is returning None.

@khelwood yes self.DB_connection() returns None. i dont know why it's doing this locally but it works in the lambda console

Ensure DB_connection() returns a valid connection:
Your DB_connection() method should return the connection object from pymysql when successful.
In case of an error, ensure that you either raise an exception or handle the None value appropriately.
Check for None in logging_sp():
Before proceeding with with self.DB_connection(), you should verify that the connection object (cnxn) is not None.
import os 
import json
import platform
import pymysql as pm
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import logging

class LogOutput:
    env = None
    config = None
    

    def __init__(self, env_filename):
        self.env = env_filename
        self.config = self.get_config()

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)
        
    def is_Windows():
        return "win" in platform.system().lower()

    def DB_connection(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        connection = None
        try:
            config = self.config

            host = config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["host"]
            port = config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["port"]
            database = config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["db"]
            username = config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["username"]
            password = config["DB_conn_info_local"]["database-secrets"]["password"]

            # Establish the connection
            connection = pm.connect(user=username, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database)
            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection
    
    def logging_sp(self):
        logging_sp_query = """
        stored procedure query here
        """
        
        cnxn = self.DB_connection()
        if cnxn is None:
            logging.error("Database connection is None. Cannot proceed.")
            return  # we exit here if there's no valid connection
            
        with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
            try:
                cur.execute(logging_sp_query)
            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception(e)
            else:
                cnxn.commit()
        cnxn.close()  # we have to close the connection afterwards

def main():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    if "win" in platform.system().lower():
        vfc = os.path.join(cwd, "DB_conn_info_local.json")
    else:
        vfc = os.path.join(cwd, "DB_conn_info_local.json")
    
    ve = LogOutput(vfc)
    ve.logging_sp()
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



ahh ok i ran this and it says: Unable to connect to database: 'DB_conn_info_local'
ERROR:root:Database connection is None. Cannot proceed.

check your DB_conn_info_local.json file

it has to do with you _local.json file, check that the path is correct, make sure it contains the necessary connection infos

ah youre right, i had the wrong conn info

@Forgottenluv you might consider uploading your DB_conn_info_local.json" file

@Forgottenluv did it work?

yes i was referring to my config incorrectly, it works now

@Forgottenluv mark this response as the answer
